# Trouble with multiple buttons to play sounds Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, button, mediaelement

Here is three standard `buttons` with the media element in xaml :

```
<Button Content="Sound1"
            Click="Button_Click1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"  
            VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <MediaElement x:Name="PlaySound1"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    />

    <Button Content="Sound2" 
            Click="Button_Click2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"  
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Margin="177,72,177,0"
            Width="126"/>
    <MediaElement x:Name="PlaySound2"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    />

    <Button Content="Sound3" 
            Click="Button_Click3"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="177,149,177,0"                      
            Width="126" />
    <MediaElement x:Name="PlaySound3"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    />
```

Here is The simple code I used, and when I try to play a third button, it doesn't work, I clicked the `buttons` in all combinations (first the `button2`, button3, and `button1`) and it doesn't worked.

```
private void Button_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PlaySound1.Source = new Uri("sound.wma", UriKind.Relative);
    PlaySound1.Stop();
    PlaySound1.Play();
}

private void Button_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PlaySound2.Source = new Uri("sound2.wma", UriKind.Relative);
    PlaySound2.Stop();
    PlaySound2.Play();

}

private void Button_Click3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PlaySound3.Source = new Uri("sound3.wma", UriKind.Relative);
    PlaySound3.Stop();
    PlaySound3.Play();
}
```

What is the correct method to use multiple buttons with multiple sounds?

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you add a .Source it will play the sound. And, by default, Stop won't work. In your initialization, set the .LoadedBehavior to Manual and assign the sources.

```
    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        PlaySound1.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        PlaySound2.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        PlaySound3.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        PlaySound1.Source = new Uri("aah-01.wav", UriKind.Relative);
        PlaySound2.Source = new Uri("crowd-groan.wav", UriKind.Relative);
        PlaySound3.Source = new Uri("laugh-01.wav", UriKind.Relative);

        base.OnInitialized(e);
    }
```

then you can have

```
    private void Button_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlaySound1.Stop();
        PlaySound1.Play();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
private void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Button button = sender as Button;
switch(button.Name)
{
case "sound1":
PlaySound1.Stop();
PlaySound1.Source= new Uri("sound.wma",UriKind.Relative);
PlaySound1.Play();
break;
case "sound2":
PlaySound2.Stop();
PlaySound2.Source= new Uri("sound2.wma",UriKind.Relative);
PlaySound2.Play();
break;
case "sound3":
PlaySound3.Stop();
PlaySound3.Source= new Uri("sound3.wma",UriKind.Relative);
PlaySound3.Play();
break;
}
}
```